# Don't require URL for an application in the developer story

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, developer-story

I want to use the developer story to chronicle the projects I have worked on. However, my employer requires strict client confidentiality, so I cannot disclose a name or URL. Please make the URL field for "feature/app" optional.

Comment: What about providing a URL to a written (and possibly redacted) summary of your work, or a URL to an obviously invalid location like http://confidential.disclosure-not-permitted.invalid/ ? That is arguably not the true purpose of the URL field but no reasonable employer would see that as deceptive.

Comment: @RobertColumbia That's an awfully hacky work-around for what is a very common problem that many of us would encounter.

Comment: yup there's nda in every big company. SE should follow it too..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your feedback. We understand that some employers ask for confidentiality and moreover some projects (feature & apps) can be done offline, therefore we won't require the URL field in the future (you can expect this to be shipped in the following weeks).