# Unable to edit the URLs for qualifications in the Developer Story

Tags: support, developer-story

The link for the courses and some institutions in my [Developer Story](https://stackoverflow.com/users/story/3956566?view=Timeline) are going to 404 page errors. I am unable to edit them.

You can see in the image - it is greyed out - it's not editable.

[image]

I'm on an Apple Mac using Chrome.

Related, but not duplicate:

- *[How do I edit a position or open source project in a Developer Story?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/339495/how-do-i-edit-a-position-or-open-source-project-in-a-developer-story)*
- *[How do I edit the title and links in my "developer story"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346173/how-do-i-edit-the-title-and-links-in-my-developer-story)*
- *[Don't require URL for an application in the developer story](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/336335/dont-require-url-for-an-application-in-the-developer-story)*

Answer (score 1):

You have to actually edit the University for the URL to become editable. Not the most intuitive design.

[image]

Comment: I suspect as people are adding institutions - the URL that is being used is being reused when that University is reused.